# How can i consolidate this SQL rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, t-sql

Let's say I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lease]
(
    [unitcode] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [chargecode] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Jan] [INT] NULL,
    [feb] [INT] NULL,
    [mar] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Lease (UNITCODE, CHARGECODE, JAN, FEB, MAR)
VALUES (001, 'RENT', 100, null, null),
       (001, 'RENT', null, 200, null),
       (001, 'RENT', null, null, 300),
       (001, 'PARKING', 50, 50, 50);
```

I am trying to consolidate the 'rent' columns into one row - this row would show all the non null values for jan, feb and mar. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Here is the current output:

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Thank you,
Asif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for a simple aggregation and Group By

Assuming you want RENT as the top line, I added the conditional sort.

**Example**

```
Select unitcode
      ,chargecode
      ,Jan = sum(Jan)
      ,Feb = sum(Feb)
      ,Mar = sum(Mar)
 From lease
 Group By unitcode
         ,chargecode
 Order By unitcode
         ,case when chargecode='Rent' then 0 else 1 end
         ,chargecode
```

**Returns**

```
unitcode    chargecode  Jan Feb Mar
1           RENT        100 200 300
1           PARKING     50  50  50
```

Comment: I hate the commas at the beginning of the line, but the answer is still the right answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have no idea what that means  :)

Comment: @AsifBinZahir Always happy to help

Comment: @GordonLinoff OH HATE.  without my glasses I saw HAVE.   Why? easier to comment out.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I'm a human being who learned how to read and write English with proper punctuation.  Commas at the beginning of lines and not followed by a space just contradict how I use language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You have a surprising take on this.  Code is not Prose.  Chamberlain & Boyce could have just as easily selected a Pipe or Tilde or even the phrase RubberDucky as the delimiter for expressions.   You know full well that the eye will recognize patterns faster than content.   Now as for me, I hate {some long expression} as SomeName.